# Mock sub-processes in Activiti

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, activiti, bpmn

Is it possible to mock the sub-process nodes in Activiti BPMN framework? I have a pretty complex workflow hierarchy which is really hard to test and mocking of sub-processes will make it much easier.
Sample code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write a java code to create the xml using any of the available API's like JAXB or Jackson to create a mock sub process xml and deploy. In this u just have to fill in the details through java and populate the XML. Example: If you are using Activiti in your application or you are creating an application on top of activiti you can easily do it. I'm creating an application on top of activiti 5.10 where user can create as many sub process(it can be independent or recursive subprocess within another subprocess) as needed with just a single right click and providing parameters.

Comment: I've also thought about similar approach. To create a dummy process (with start and end event) and then, somehow, replace the actual call activity with dummy one before starting the process.